# how to add personal detail on sharepoint

Tags: user-profile

I need to create a share point page that contains some information about each user.

For some information about user, it seems that i have to use list for some details like work history, but my problem is that i don't know what to use for form informations that the user have to fill once (personal id , address , phone# , section code , ... )

I thinks about survey, but unable to edit survey.

Comment: list is not useful for me, because i need those data not to be in a list form, those should not be able to repeated. for example you have just one home address or one office number

Comment: What version of SharePoint? Wouldn't the user profile services work? Or "My Settings" depending on what version you're on.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use a custom list. You'd create the list and columns specific to your needs and create a view to see the information how you'd like. Then, an editor will be able to insert new records into this list one at a time or through datasheet mode. If you want to create a form that allows users to fill out this information themselves, you could look into using a custom infopath form that is tied to this list.

Comment: when you register somewhere in real world you have to fill a form that have several type of data , the second part usually is information about your history that are like a list that you can add several rows, but the first part is some personal information like first-name/last-name/eye-color/birth date/marital status/picture/ and ... that the person have to fill or update in just one record, and have no meaning if filled like a list; the problem is how to define the no-list section .

Comment: in the other hand, how to limit that list to just one record?